# How to use Higher Order function (or alternative) for wrapping a React component without the component continually unmounting?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-functions

I have a React component (`Parent`) within which there is another componet (`Child`) that is wrapped using a Higher Order function (`HOWrapper`). The problem I am having is that each time the `Parent` component renders, the `Child` component unmounts and then re-mounts. I need to find a way that prevents the `Child` component from unmounting, but still continue to wrap it in a component whose name is dynamically assigned. I also want the option to pass additional parameters to the `HOWrapper` function, that may also be dynamically generated in the `render()` function of `Parent`. Any ideas?

Parent component:

```
import { HOWrapper } from './somepath';
import Child from './someotherpath';
export default class Parent extends Component {
    ...
    render(){

        let ChildWrapper = HOWrapper(Child);

        return (
            <ChildWrapper {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}
```

Higher Order function:

```
export function HOWrapper(WrappedComponent) {
    return class Blanket extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                ...
            };
        }

        ...

        render() {
            return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    {...this.props}
                />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're taking advantage of a HOC component here. Why can't you just pass custom props to your child component? In your example you're not passing any custom information to the HOC so it would seem that you could just export the child with the hoc wrapped one single time

Comment: Not sure where you're coming from - would you be able to provide and answer demonstrating this?

Comment: Sure, but I feel like it will be an incomplete answer because you haven't stated in detail what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because an HOC returns a component, a more typical approach to using them is once when exporting them, not on every render call.

```
let YourComponent = props => <div />
export default HOC(YourComponent)
```

Then if you want to do anything dynamic pass new props to it.

```
render() { return <YourComponent dynamicProps={foo} /> }
```